# DXSDK linker problem

Tags: directx

I have installed VS2k10 and DXSDK on my comp.
I have started a new project, then added the include and the lib/x64 dir in the VC++
directories. I have also added d3dx10.lib and d3d10.lib in additional dependencies.
But I am keep getting the " error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D3D10CreateDeviceAndSwapChain@32 referenced in function ..." error.
Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you that you're missing the link to the 32-bit version of d3d10.lib, so make sure you're either linking that under Project > Properties > Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, or change the target of your application to 64-bit under Solution > Configuration Manager.